# MySQL GROUP BY - showing X results per Group

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have two tables. One for **people** and one for **cars**. Now I want to show a list of all cars, limiting them to two cars per people.

With

```
SELECT   c.*, 
         p.* 
FROM     cars   c, 
         people p 
WHERE    c.carOwnerPeopleId = p.peopleId 
GROUP BY p.peopleId
```

I already limit it to 1 car per people. But how do I do  a group by to show 2 cars?

Table people

```
peopleId
peopleName
```

Table cars

```
carId
carOwnerPeopleId
carBrand
carName
```

Results could be:

```
carId, carOwnerPeopleId, carBrand, carName, peopleId, peopleName
1, 1, BMW, Series 3, 1, Jon
1, 1, Audi, A4, 1, Jon
1, 1, Mercedes, SL AMG, 1, Jon
```

But now I want to cap it at 2 results for a "Jon".

Comment: @GordonLinoff indeed, two tables, excuse the translation aspect.

Comment: @Lars, update your question with sample data , db structure and how results should be

Comment: Please update the OP with your table structure as well as some sample data.

Comment: @sagivasan hope thats clear enough...

Comment: @daZza     done :) !

Answer (score 1):

In MySQL, the best way is probably to use variables:

```
select c.*
from people p join
     (select c.*,
             (@rn := if(@p = c.carOwnerPeopleId, @rn + 1,
                        if(@p := c.carOwnerPeopleId, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from cars c cross join
           (select @p := -1, @rn := 0) params
      order by c.carOwnerPeopleId
     ) c
     on c.carOwnerPeopleId = p.PeopleId
where rn <= 2;
```

You can add a second key to `order by` if you want two particular cars (two newest, two biggest, two reddest or whatever).

Comment: Is this the most performant method? Or is filtering via PHP maybe more efficient?

Comment: @Lars . . . You would have to test it out to see which is better.  If you had 20,000,000 rows and only one person, with an index on `cars(carOwnerPeopleId)`, then it is probably faster to do the work in the database.